# GPS reading from background service in android on regular interval?

Tags: android, gps, background-service

In my application I want to get user's current locations's details using GPS, if GPS is not available it should get details from network provider. I need to update all location details on regular interval i.e after every half hour. 
So what should I do for this? Can I use background service for this? If yes then will it affect battery life or can we get location details on regular basis using background service in android?
Please tell me something for this. Or tutorial will be great idea.

Comment: Please read this tutorial http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html

Comment: hey thanks will update you as soon as I try.